# Grunt with grunt-sass (libsass wrapper), slow compile time

Tags: sass, gruntjs

When I run `time sassc app.scss app.css`, the compilation time is very fast:
`sassc` is a commandline wrapper for C implementation on `libsass` library.

```
real    __0m0.132s__
user    0m0.123s
sys 0m0.007s
```

However when using `grunt-sass` which is `Node.js` wrapper for `libsass`,
inside my `Gruntfile.js`, I get much slower output:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
File "stylesheets/sass/app.scss" changed.
Running "sass:compile" (sass) task
File ./stylesheets/app.css created.

Done, without errors.
Completed in __1.759s__ at Sat May 24 2014 18:17:33 GMT+0200 (CEST) - Waiting...
```

and here are the relevant parts of my `Gruntfile.js`, maybe I did here something wrong:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        project: {
            app: '.',
            sheets: '<%= project.app %>/stylesheets',
            sass: [ '<%= project.sheets %>/sass/app.scss',
            ],
            js: [],
        },
        // The watch task is used to run tasks in response to file changes
        watch: {
            options: {
                livereload: true,
            },
            html: {
                files: ['<%= project.app %>/*.html'],
            },
            css: {
                files: ['<%= project.sheets %>/*.css'],
            },
            sass: {
                files: '<%= project.sheets %>/sass/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}',
                tasks: ['sass:compile'],
                options: {
                    livereload: false,
                },
            },

        },
        sass: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    style: 'nested',
                },

                files: {
                    '<%= project.sheets %>/app.css' : '<%= project.sheets %>/sass/app.scss',
                }
            }
        },

    }); // The end of grunt.initConfig

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');

    grunt.registerTask('preview', ['watch', ]);
};
```

Why am I getting such a slow compilation time, in Grunt?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having similar problems

Comment: Got to the bottom of my issue. It was because I was saving over the network... Duh!

Comment: @branquito did you maybe solve your problem?

Comment: @TheFrost No I didn't. What I did is, I used `entr` [http://entrproject.org/] for compile on demand in combination with `sassc`, which gives great speed on compiling, and then use `grunt` for other tasks if needed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know if this will help you, but when I had a similar problem, I found that sourcemap generation (*which is enabled by default*) will slow down compilation time.

#### With sourcemap enabled:

```
$ time grunt sass:dev
grunt sass:dev  12,44s user 0,19s system 100% cpu 12,618 total
```

#### With sourcemap disabled:

```
$ time grunt sass:dev
grunt sass:dev  4,57s user 0,17s system 98% cpu 4,800 total
```

To disable sourcemap, just add `sourcemap` option and change its value to  'none':

```
sass: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            style: 'nested',
            sourcemap: 'none',
        },

        files: {
            '<%= project.sheets %>/app.css' : '<%= project.sheets %>/sass/app.scss',
        }
    }
},
```

Reference: [grunt-contrib-sass sourcemap](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass/tree/v0.8.1#sourcemap)

Comment: That's 4.57s, I had bellow 2secs, and wasn't satisfied.. Now I have those 130ms, with what I described in one of my comments.

Comment: I have over 70 scss files inside that project, which could be an explanation for those 4s :-)

Comment: A few things:

The property is camel-case: `sourceMap`. [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#sourcemap)

Setting `sourceMap` to 'none' seems to create a sourcemap named 'none' :) Setting it to a boolean `false` should prevent it from being created, but that seems to be the default behavior

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [time-grunt](https://www.npmjs.org/package/time-grunt) which you should include to measure the actual time of your sass task.

It may have to do with the watch task, with grunt startup time or something else. Therefore it would be interesting to see where the measured time is coming from and where the leak is.